# Medians from paired data

Tags: statistics, median

Let's say I have a data set of $n$ data points of $2$ variables, $x_i$ and $y_i$. Is it possible that the percentage of data points, such that $x_i$ is greater than $y_i$ can be arbitrarily high, say over $90\%$, whilst still having that the median of $y$ is greater than the median of $x$.

I have good reason to believe the answer is $yes$ but I would like to see if anyone knows of or can come up with a nice or geometric proof. Added points for an algorithm that can generate such data.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean to construct an example of $x$ and $y$ or to prove the question on *arbitrary* $x$ or $y$?

Comment: No, I am asking for a proof of arbitrary $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So your statement is false.  Consider a data set $x = \{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and $y = \{0.5,1.5,\dots,n+0.5\}$ (i.e. $x$ shifted to the right by $0.5$ units.)  Obviously, the median (and the mean) of $y$ is greater that of $x$ by $0.5$, but the "the percentage of data points, such that $x_i$ is greater than $y_i$ *is bounded* by $50\%$.

Comment: I know that there exists data sets such that it is not true. Are there data sets such that it is true?

Comment: What are you asking?  You want "for arbitrary $x$ and $y$, prove ....(question statement)".  So I give you a counterexample: "there exists $x,y$ such that ....(question statement) is wrong".  So you actually mean to construct a specific example of $x$ and $y$ so that the criterion is matched?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Sounds like he just wants a way to make up random numbers that will satisfy the criterion? I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course this is possible. Consider the data set $X = \{5,5,5,5,5,5,9,10,11,12,13\}$ and $Y = \{1,1,1,1,1,6,6,7,8,9,10\}$. The median of $Y$ ($6$) is greater than the median of $X$ ($5$), yet ~$91\%$ of the time, $x_i > y_i$. To achieve an arbitrarily high percentage, just make $n$ a large odd number for easiness and set the desired median for $X$ and $Y$. Then for $i \leq \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$, generate $x_i < median(X)$ and make $y_i = x_i - random\_num()$. For $i > \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil$, generate $y_i > median(Y)$ and make $x_i = y_i + random\_num()$. If you want additional constraints on $X$ and $Y$ so your data doesn't look so bizarrely artificial, that might be harder.